# unable to delete osb_server1 in the osb 10.3.6.0

Tags: weblogic, osb

There are scripts that build the admin server, then create clusters, managed servers, machines etc and when this domain is built, it is seen that an additional phantom server osb_server1 with port 8011, is getting built that isn't attached to any cluster or any machine.

This is built when the wlsb.jar was being referenced during one of the scripts.

Once after the admin server is up and running and we have other managed servers as well, Was trying to remove osb_server1 and this error creeps up

weblogic.management.configuration.AppDeploymentMBeanImpl.isCacheInAppDirectorySet()
Errors must be corrected before processding

There are like 120 default deployments on OSB that are targeted to osb_server1, was trying to retarget them to another server, but that is also throwing an error ...

Any ideas ???

Comment: perhaps your script creates a domain based on an existing template (like the default) which contains an osb_server?

Answer (score 0):

That's due to the weird behaviour/bug of the standard osb template. There is a discussion here. http://theheat.dk/blog/?p=1255.

I didnt follow the steps given by Oracle(as in the URL). What I did was, 
I keep the default osb_server1, and make it part of the cluster during the domain creation(ie, it's the first server). Once the domain is created, I re-set the osb_server1 to the desired value. That way the singleton services will still be deployed to the 1st server and others to cluster. Using WLST:

```
readDomain(domain_name)
cd('/Servers/osb_server1')
set('ListenPort', osb1_listen_port)
set('Name', osb1_name)
cd('/Servers/' + osb1_name + '/ServerDiagnosticConfig/osb_server1')
set('Name', osb1_name)
updateDomain()
closeDomain()
```